# How to use the observer to check if a div is visible or not? (maybe Azure server problem?)

Tags: javascript, azure, observers

I need to check without further action if an element on my page is currently visible (this is being set either by button click or function call).

The observer seems to be the right tool from what I have read so far.
On my local machine everything works fine. But on my Azure test server I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'ResizeObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
function setStatus() {
    var target = $('#sidebar_container');

    var ro = new ResizeObserver(() => {
        if (target.is(':visible')) {
            $("i.fa-user").addClass("active");
        } else {
            $("i.fa-user").removeClass("active");
        }        
    });

    // Observe element
    ro.observe(target);
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code (although it's working on localhost) or is there a setting on the Azure server I would have to check?

Comment: Hi JonSnow, are you working with jquery?. I believe that object returned by jquery `$` is not an element try with `target.element`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you posted, it looks like you are testing this functionality on localhost by resizing your window.

I'm saying this because, to check if an element has come into the viewport, you should use the [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), not the Resize Observer.

You'll find a deep dive into how this observer works in the MDN link above.

To simply check if an element is inside the viewport (so it should be "visible") this is a possible solution:

```js
// Get a reference for the target element
let element = document.querySelector('#sidebar_container');

// Create a function that will handle any intersection between some elements and the viewport.
let handleIntersection = function (entries) {

    // Loop through all the observed elements
    for (let entry of entries) {

        // Check if the element is intersecting the viewport
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            console.log("The following element is visible in the viewport: ", entry.target);
            // ...
        }
    }
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);

observer.observe(element);
```

Also, you should pass to the observer an actual DOM element, not the jQuery wrapper. For this, it would be probably better to just use `document.querySelector` to select the element rather then jQuery.
In the devtools the $ sign is a shortcut to the querySelector, so if you were trying this code directly through the devtools, this might have triggered some confusion.

Comment: Ah, ok, I am using the querySeelctor now, good point. About Intersection Observer... wow, huge documentation. But where to integrate the "is visible or not" question here? I have never used ANY observer so far :-/

Comment: Hi Jon, i've updated the anser with a little example of how you can use the observer, I admit that the article is very deep, but also complicated.

Comment: So it's "isIntersecting" instead of is(":visible"). That's definitively something that's absolutely new to me! I have already learned a lot from your explanations - thanks for this. Tomorrow morning I will give your function a try. I am curious!!

Comment: Good morning Drago, tested it and it works great - just not on every page. Still getting the same error on a few sub folders. No idea what, but I guess, this is a different problem (publishing on Azure server caused "interesting" errors in the past...)

Comment: Question: if observer.observe(element) throws an error (for whatever reason): is it possible to continue with the rest of my code? Currently the error from above is blocking the execution from the rest of the JS

Comment: If you want, you can include it in a try-catch, but it really shouldn't throw any error. If it's throwing the error that you originally posted, please use console.log to check what is the value of the element you are passing to the "observe" function. It's probable that it is not initialized correctly

Comment: Thx Drago. At the end I was able to solve the problem. It was a combination: the target div is in a partial view. The test server is extremely slow, so sometimes the partial view wasn't yet loaded when the script was searching for the div. That caused the error. Then in addition there was a publishing bug with the Azure server. Publishing the whole solution did not properly update all pages on the server. I had to manually copy them folder by folder. Then it finally worked ....

Comment: Perfect! Happy to know that it now works :)